# When to use parameter vs. when to use member variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Are there any indicators to deciding whether to use a parameter or member variable?

See below example:

```
open class BankAccount(val accountCode: String, val accountName: String, 
var balance : Double = 0.0) {}
```

vs.

```
open class BankAccount(val accountCode: String, val accountName: String) {}
var balance : Double = 0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Use a parameter if you need to parameterise.

---

In the first case, you will be able to start an account with a non-zero balance.

If that is a scenario you find useful, it makes sense to make the `balance` an (optional) parameter. Otherwise, a member variable is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also tell me when you should and shouldn't add `val` to `accountCode`?

Comment: Without the `val` the parameter will only be accesible to (the body of) the constructor itself. It will not become a property/field.

Answer (score 4):

The only question you have to ask is "Is this something that should be set via the constructor?" If yes, then use a parameter. If not, use a property. By adding `var` you're still making the declaration a property, you're just also adding a shortcut to initialize it from the constructor.

If you're coming from a Java background, looking at the Java equivalent would be helpful. It would be something like this:

```
public class BankAccount {
    private final String mAccountCode;
    private final String mAccountName;
    private double mBalance;

    public BankAccount(String accountCode, String accountName, double balance) {
        mAccountCode = accountCode;
        mAccountName = accountName;
        mBalance = balance;
    }

    public BankAccount(String accountCode, String accountName) {
        this(accountCode, accountName, 0.0d)
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        mBalance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return mBalance;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
public class BankAccount {
    private final String mAccountCode;
    private final String mAccountName;
    private double mBalance = 0.0d;

    public BankAccount(String accountCode, String accountName) {
        mAccountCode = accountCode;
        mAccountName = accountName;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        mBalance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return mBalance;
    }
}
```

Notice that you get a constructor argument for the balance field in the first case. In either case you can update the value with a method call to the setter.

---

For your second question, when you should and shouldn't use `val` or `var`, the answer is "Use var to make the parameter a writable property, use val to make it a read-only property, and use nothing if you just want constructor args.

Again, the Java equivalent of something like this:

```
open class Example(var writable : Int, val readable : Int, constructorArg : Int) {

    // Could use constructor arg to init another property
    private val someOtherProperty : Int = constructorArg

    // Or in the init block (the Kotlin "constructor" body)
    init {
        // Or do something with constructArg in the constructor
    }
}
```

Would be something like this:

```
public class Example {
    private int mWritable;
    private final int mReadable;
    private final int mSomeOtherProperty;

    public Example(int writable, int readable, int contructorArg) {
        mWritable = writeable;
        mReadable = readable;

        // Could use constructor arg to init another property
        mSometOtherProperty = constructorArg;

        // Or do something with constructArg in the constructor
    }

    public int getWritable() {
        return mWritable;
    }

    public void setWritable(int writable) {
        mWritable = writable;
    }

    public int getReadable() {
        return mReadable;
    }
```

The `var` attribute makes a property that has both a setter and a getter so you can update it.
The `val` attribute makes a property that only has a getter so you can read it.
The arg with no keyword makes no property - instead it is passed to the constructor for you to use as needed. This is a trivialized example so it does nothing, but in reality you would use it to either initialize other properties or with an `init` block.

---

Again, assuming you're coming from a Java background, you can use Intellij to run view the Kotlin byte code, then convert that to Java to see what the differences in the language do.

Here's the first google hit that explains this:
https://medium.com/@mydogtom/tip-how-to-show-java-equivalent-for-kotlin-code-f7c81d76fa8

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks great write-up. Is there any case where omitting the `val/var` keyword is beneficial over using it? Seeing as `val/var` has read/write permissions, no keyword seems to have no benefit.

Comment: Without the `val/var` the parameter will only be accesible to (the body of) the constructor itself. It will not become a property/field. So if you need this only for some calculation within the constructor, you don't need to store it in a field.

Comment: Yeah, it's no so much is it "beneficial" - it's "what the purpose"? You could say the "benefit" of omitting the keywords is that there's no unnecessary property created if you're not going to use it. Intellij will warn you about this.